# I am trying to write code in matlab for inner current control loop, my aim is minimizing error, need code verification

Tags: matlab, optimization, diagram, pid-controller, feedback-loop

I am trying to write following inner current control loop structure in MATLAB. Both these diagrams are inter related and using these diagrams I made a following code, my aim in this code is to minimize id*-id, i am doing this by using ITEA. plz help me in verifying this code. the diagram is in image link below. i have implemented that link in code below.

`

Comment: in terms of value what should i do?

Comment: Have you considered Simulink? Also, you need to  elaborate a bit more. Provide more details.

Comment: i dont wanna use matlab simulink, im just using m file for coding, its a inner current controller loop for vsc based hvdc systm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to connect a block diagram is to use [append](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/append.html)/[connect](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/connect.html). Your system actually is [image: system].

To connect the output, we need the additional block 7 (we can not connect the system output to the input of some block, only to the output):
 [image: new system]

So, the code can look like this:

```
sys1= tf(1,[Lt Rt]);
sys2= omega*Lt;
sys3= omega*Lt;
sys4= tf(1,[Lt Rt]);
sys5= (Kp + Ki/s);
sys6=(Kp + Ki/s);
sys7 = 1;
system= append(sys1,sys2,sys3,sys4,sys5,sys6,sys7);
connections= [ 1 2 -5;
    2 4 0;
    3 1 0;
    4 -3 -6;
    5 7 0;
    6 -4 0;
    7 -1 0];  
inputs=  [7 4 5 6];
outputs= 7; 
system= connect(system,connections,inputs,outputs);
```

Note that you can't use name-based and index-based connections at one time.

Comment: after writing this code, should i make this block in simulink as well? or this code is enough to make a diagram in m file?

Comment: what about inputs section?are these just random no, or assigned by connections command?

Comment: No, you should not. This code uses the Control System Toolbox functions. It does not use Simulink in any way

Comment: `inputs` contains the indices of the blocks connected to the global system input

Comment: plus how i can add this block output to input of the other in the picture?

Comment: You can use the same method, `append` and `connect` the constructed blocks

Comment: so if i want to add any input to this block, what is the code for it, for example ed=0.4, input=[0.4,'1'], does it goes like that?

Comment: As far as I understand, you mean simulation. It is a different question and it requires a separate answer. Briefly, you can use `step` (if your input is a constant) or `lsim` functions

Comment: no sir, i am asking this question in terms of matlab coding not simulation.

Comment: how i can the `vq` and `vq` inputs  in this code, plus if if i want to give some values to inputs and output how i should do that?

Comment: You mean the open-loop control (the input of the system is equal to some u(t), in particular, u(t)=const). The open loop control information is not stored in lti objects. You should provide it for modeling the output of your system (when using `step`, `lsim` or smth else) This modeling is called simulation, it has nothing to do with Simulink

Comment: `vq` and `vq`  can be added using additional -1 gain blocks connected to the inputs.